# Guide on how to modify the ADMIN UI in keystoneJS

Tags: node.js, browserify, keystone

I'm pretty new to the nodejs express and keystone world.
It's some days by now i try to modify the ADMIN UI, and i managed to add some permissions:
-added isVeryAdmin role to users so only this kind of user can see all the posts delete and modify them.
-rest of the users that are flagged with isAdmin can access the Admin UI and see modify and delete only the content assigned to them.

However i had not understood the Admin UI + browserify management, i would like to show in the UI only certain things to different roles, but in

`node_modules/keystone/admin/server/templates/index.html`

there is reference to `<%= adminPath %>/js/fields.js"` that i can't find nowhere.

i saw the contribute file but i am not able to activate the KEYSTONE_DEV feature.
can you give me some suggestions on how to keep my work going and maybe contribute better to the enviroment?

Comment: I'm going through the same thing. Kinda tough reverse engineering the build process for the new reactjs admin ui. I think perhaps they prefer it this way... I'm simply trying to tailor mine to fit my design preference, and I can't even manage that! Not yet anyway. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I did manage to display different things to different roles but i don't remember exactly how. I remember that i changed the source code of the framework. If i can give you a suggestion have a look at firebase as an alternative as a server. there is a service that acts as a CMS for firebase called Flamelink.

Comment: I also have been modifying the source code. Pain to sift through the reactjs build! Wouldn't be so bad if I could figure out how to modify the individual react files and re-build the app. I'm not very well-versed in reactjs yet, so for now I'm just making changes to the source. I've actually achieved most of what I'm looking for. Firebase isn't well-suited for my particular use-case, thanks though!